# What is the correct way to subclass QAbstractListModel for a changing but read-only model?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I've read and tried various things, mainly those listed here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html

So basically I have some C++ class that contains a list of things with a few properties. This list of things changes basically out of my control (hardware/network nodes appearing and leaving) and emits a signal that it changed.

What I've been doing for testing is expose a C++ type with a `QStringList` property. This works fine, but does not allow exposing multiple properties, and it also resets the view for every update.

C++

```
Q_PROPERTY(QStringList robots READ robots NOTIFY robotsChanged)

QStringList StatusInfo::robots() {
    auto samples = statusReader.read();
    QStringList dataList;
    for (auto& sample: samples) {
        std::string id = sample->data().id();
        dataList.append(QString::fromStdString(id));
    }
    return dataList;
}

void StatusInfo::on_data_available( dds::sub::DataReader<Operator::StatusInformation>& dr) {
    emit robotsChanged();
}
```

QML:

```
    ListView {
      id: robotList
      model: status.robots
      delegate: RobotItem {}
    }
```

The other option is subclassing `QAbstractListModel`, which seems to be the "proper" way to make a more complex model. Except it's not clear which methods I need to override and which signals to emit.

From the section on [subclassing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html#subclassing):

> When subclassing QAbstractListModel, you must provide implementations of the rowCount() and data() functions. Well behaved models also provide a headerData() implementation.

Okay, so much is clear. Every model needs this.

> For editable list models, you must also provide an implementation of setData(), and implement the flags() function so that it returns a value containing Qt::ItemIsEditable.

My model is not editable, so no.

> Models that provide interfaces to resizable list-like data structures can provide implementations of insertRows() and removeRows(). When implementing these functions, it is important to call the appropriate functions so that all connected views are aware of any changes.

This is where it gets tricky. I don not want to provide an interface for a resizable list-like data structure. But the length of my model *will* change.

To further complicate matters, the above `DataReader` just returns a list of items, not some nice insert commands, so there is no simple way to just call `beginInsertRows` and friends.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Your question is very broad and gaseous, if you provide a [mcve] you could give a real answer.

Comment: You might find it easier to start from an existing model subclass, such as `QAbstractListModel` - most of the index management is then done for you.

Comment: How is it too broad? I mentioned a specific scenario: What is the proper way to make a model for a read-only but changing dataset? I also literally wrote about QAbstractListModel.

Comment: @Pepijn 
What is your data? Does each item represent a string or a QObject or a particular object?

Comment: @Pepijn you point: *but does not allow exposing multiple properties*, what properties do you mean?

Comment: Can you elaborate why `beginInsertRows` and friends are not possible? You might want to take a look at the source of `QSortFilterProxyModel` - when you get a new list, you first calculate the changes, and then you `insertRows` and `removeRows` as necessary with calling the necessary functions and updating the `(row)Count`.

Comment: https://github.com/benlau/qsyncable might work for you, you pass it your full data as a list of QVariantMap and it handle the change signals and model part for you. It makes a diff of its current data and the new data and it calls `(begin|end)(Insert|Remove)Rows` and `dataChanged` automatically.

Comment: Yea, it appears "calculate the changes" is where it's at. Alright.

Comment: If you want to expose multiple properties, use roles as described here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qabstractitemmodel-subclass
Instead of using `QStringList`, use `QAbstractListModel` subclass object as a model directly and override functions `rowCount`, `data` and `roleNames` and use `dataChanged` to signal changes in the read-only model